# VPS-based proxy slow

Tags: proxy, vps, throttling

I have a VPS running Ubuntu that I'm trying to use as a proxy server:

```
ssh sysuser_e@XXXXX.hostserv.eu -D 192.168.233.1:12321
```

where 192.168.233.1 is one of my local IP-addresses.

I've added this proxy config to my Firefox network settings as socks5 proxy.

The setup almost works but the connection is terribly slow and practically unusable:
[image]

At the same time

- the SSH-connection to the VPS is quite good, around 100 Mbit/s when downloading files with `scp`.
- similar proxy connection to a dedicated server yields great speed, also around 100Mbit/s - this is a work server, so I only used it as to compare/benchmark

I know that the VPS host throttles the systems in terms of both disk I/O and CPU but I assumed the network should be uncapped? What do I need to know about VPS services that would allow me to use the proxy at decent speed?

FWIW I have root access to that VPS. The ssh client runs on Windows 10, tried both git-bash and Putty.

**EDIT**. As requested, tried it with cURL as well:

Local to VPS
[image]
VPS to VPS
[image]

Comment: Overhead of dynamic SSH forwarding (exposed to clients as SOCKS) is non-negligible. What’s your opinion on using a VPN and/or HTTP proxy instead?

Comment: What kind of CPU do you see on the CPU? It should be fairly low even for 100 Mbps, well below artificial throttling, but check just in case there's a runaway process or something.

Comment: Just to make sure, is it a KVM/Xen VPS or an OpenVZ container? Does the problem also affect non-browsers (e.g. curl with proxy)? Does it affect non-SOCKS mode (i.e. do -L tunnels have the same problem)? Does the problem still occur if you SSH *from the VPS* back to itself (essentially, proxying over localhost) and run the curl test remotely?

Comment: @DanielB Can I torrent over an HTTP proxy?

Comment: @u1686_grawity CPU usage is seemingly low, i.e. 10-20% for `sshd`, with other processed idle. cURL results added to question

Comment: Can you test a) after setting `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0` on the server (effective for new connections), and b) with the option `IPQoS none none` or maybe `IPQoS cs0 cs0` in the server's sshd_config? (remember to restart sshd)

Comment: @u1686_grawity quite humiliating to me the issue was actually with all ssh traffic - scp was also when I retested it again. So you're absolutely correct in your reasoning